# PHP returning output of other user request

Tags: php, mysql, session, iis, fastcgi

I'm facing the problem with PHP response. I used Ajax with 3 seconds delay to check the user's logs. When the user account used simultaneously with two users, one must be kicked. I used to track the log id in db if equal with the session. The problem is some users are getting kicked even there is no other user using his/her account. I tried to `print_r` the query statements and it is returning different values. It might be the response for other users.

I'm using IIS server and FastCGI for PHP response.

Can somebody tell me how this possible and give me ideas to solve this issue? Thanks.

Here is some of the codes :

Checking logs in DB using Ajax:

```
public function CheckLogStatus( $name, $email, $sess_code ) { 

    $qry = "Select log from $this->tablename where name='$name' and email='$email'";
    //when I print this statement it returns different values of $name and $email

    $result = mysql_query( $qry ) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if( !$selResult = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    if( !isset( $selResult['log'] ) && $selResult['log'] != '' ) {
        if( $selResult['log'] != $sess_code ) {
            //$_SESSION['LOGS'] = 'USED';
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: without any code its difficult to help

Comment: +1, and the first thing that comes to my mind is you may have forgotten to implement "logout" in the db.

Comment: Store the session log value as cookie in user's browser, then access the cookie and compare! this may work!

Comment: When logging in system updating the lod id. if someone is logged using the same account, his/her session id will be expired and will be automatically kicked. so log out don't affect it.

Comment: hmmm. @venkat sounds interesting. can you give a session config for it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['LOG'] = $log;
setcookie("Log",$log,time()*24*60*60); //expires after 24hrs
?>
```

The function CheckLogStatus is same as you mentioned above,

```
<?php
public function CheckLogStatus( $name, $email, $sess_code ){
$qry = "Select log from $this->tablename where name='$name' and email='$email'";
$result = mysql_query( $qry ) or die(mysql_error());
if( !$selResult = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
return false;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
if( !isset( $selResult['log'] ) && $selResult['log'] != '' ){ 

         if( $selResult['log'] != $sess_code ) {
    return false;
}
}

return true;
}
?>
```

but while passing,

```
<?php
CheckLogStatus( "Myname", "contact@email.com", $_COOKIE['Log'] );
?>
```

Comment: Check the answer above, i have just added the method to pass and get the cookie! and not updating in database!(hope you done that well)

Comment: Can you also give a resource or answer may explain why session is not good for it?

Comment: I don't know about that! But cookie is stored, so that it exists even after user closes the browser! but session expires when user closes his/her browser!